# Счетчик блокировки не умеет считать

Tags: дефект

*(заголовок для кликбейта, счетчик считать умеет, но блокировка отлючается намного позднее)*

Во время блокировки в профиле висит плашка, что участник заблокирован и блокировка истекает через Х дней, потом "дней" сменяется на "часов", потом "часов" сменяется на "минут", потом на "секунд", и в самый последний момент плашка выглядит так:

[image: счетчик блокировки]

И потом исчезает. Однако!, хоть срок блокировки и "истечёт немедленно", сама блокировка не отлючается еще минут двадцать точно, а то и несколько часов.

Comment: Думаю, дело в [Eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). Вряд ли это решается надёжно.

Comment: Во всём виновато кеширование.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ  ох уж эти орехи!!